# Forecasting and Structural Breaks

Tags: econometrics, time-series, forecasting

Let's say I am using walkforward evaluation for forecasting a certain time series with ARIMA and I want to test for structural breaks. And then I detect structural breaks. How can I use this information in my forecasting model? Or is it more for analysis of time series rather than forecasting>

Comment: Hi @a12345. There are multiple ways you might want to account for this information, but probably the most robust would be to use a model with time-varying parameters.

Comment: This question may be a better fit for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forecasting?tab=Newest) Stack Exchange where forecasting is a major topic with 3800+ threads (and ARIMA with nearly 3000, and structural change with nearly 300).

Comment: @EB3112  What are some examples of time varying models?  One thing I was thinking of, is when there is a structural break, it might be a good time select p,d,q for the ARIMA model.

Comment: @RichardHardy Ok I might move it there if this does not get enough traction.